# How to correctly setup TeamServer build to run .NET Core project with XUnit

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, xunit

I have following project

```
/proj.sln
/some.lib.test/ 
    /some.lib.test.csproj
```

where 
some.lib.test.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>    
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.0-beta5-build3769" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.0-beta5-build3769" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{82a7f48d-3b50-4b1e-b82e-3ada8210c358}" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

How to setup Team Services build to get tests normally viewed?

I try to search web but don't get valid result.

`dotnet test` - works, but not create VSTS report
`dotnet xunit` - don't work at all (cannot be used at sln level i think)
`VSTS Test Task` - don't sees any results

In logs:

In logs:

c:\bin\vs\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe
C:\agent_work\1\s\iskkonekb.kuvera.model.test\bin\release\netcoreapp2.0\iskkonekb.kuvera.model.test.dll /EnableCodeCoverage /logger:trx "/TestAdapterPath:"C:\agent_work\1\s\packages"" /InIsolation /UseVsixExtensions:true /Framework:FrameworkCore10

[xUnit.net 00:00:00.1787131] Skipping: iskkonekb.kuvera.model.test (Could not find any of the following assemblies: xunit.execution.desktop.dll)

I cannot find xunit.execution.desktop in NUgets

So it sees XUNit but cannot xall

Added  - not helped

Comment: agent is installed locally - can check it without TeamService

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .NET Core Test task with --logger arguments to generate the test result file, then publish test result through Publish Test Results task:

1. Delete files task (Source Folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`; Contents: `**/TestResults/**`)
2. .NET Core Restore
3. .NET Core Build
4. .NET Core Test (Arguments: `--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --logger "trx"`)
5. Publish Test Results (Test result format:`VSTest`; Test results files:`**\*.trx`; Search folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`)

Comment: Currently code coverage is not available, hopefully that'll come soon https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/981